# Modifying a report themes JSON file is not working as expected

Tags: powerbi

I have the following simple report theme file.

```
    {"name":"Phishing",
        "dataColors":["#8A3575","#371447","#CE477E","#5A225D","#1C988A","#D3D3D3","#B2B2B2","#D9B300","#3599B8","#DFBFBF","#4AC5BB","#5F6B6D","#FB8281","#F4D25A","#7F898A","#A4DDEE","#FDAB89","#B687AC","#28738A","#A78F8F","#168980","#293537","#BB4A4A","#B59525","#475052","#6A9FB0","#BD7150","#7B4F71","#1B4D5C","#706060","#0F5C55","#1C2325"],
        "visualStyles":
            {"*":
                {"*":
                    {"*":
                        [{"fontSize":11,"fontFamily":"Lato","color":{"solid":{}}}]
                    }
                }
            },
        "bad":"#D2222D","good":"#238823"
}
```

If I understand correctly, this should add the Lato font family to every visual that has a font family property. However, this is only partially happening. For example, I see Lato in the Table Values font family, and I see it in the Slicer Items font family. But, I do not see a Lato option for Cards -> Data Label font family. Nor do I see it in the Table Column Header font family.

Is there something I'm doing wrong, or something else I need to do?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to modify CARD, you must add "card" keyword as belowe:

```
{
   "name":"My Theme",
   "visualStyles":{
      "*":{
         "*":{
            "*":[
               {
                  "color":{
                     "solid":{
                        
                     }
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      },
      "card":{
         "*":{
            "labels":[
               {
                  "show":true,
                  "color":{
                     "solid":{
                        "color":"#f0ee4c"
                     }
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      },
      "tableEx":{
         "*":{
            "columnHeaders":[
               {
                  "fontColor":{
                     "solid":{
                        "color":"#f0ee4c"
                     }
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

[ThemeDocumentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-report-themes)

[EasyToUseGenerator](https://powerbi.tips/tools/report-theme-generator-v3/)

Comment: Thank you but this only partially answers my question. What about table column headers?

Comment: I have updated my answer: Add "tableEx". For more, just use the second link and generate all properties you need :)